# Ruby Websocket endpoints, EventMachine, Goliath, etc

Tags: websocket, url-routing, eventmachine, endpoint

I am fairly new to using web sockets, but I have enjoyed what I have been doing so far.

My app is currently setup with 3 endpoints based upon the path the connection is initially established with.

**EndPoint #1** - Users can connect and will only be able to receive messages.

**EndPoint #2** - Messages can be sent to a specific user.

**EndPoint #3** - Returns a status of which users are an connected and how many connections each user has.

I have not been able to find any good tutorials or examples which speak to what I am trying to do (routing). Which makes me think I may be approaching this incorrectly. However, everything seems to be working ok with my app.

Here is a sample of my router:`router.rb`

```
class Router

    def setup
        @@connections ||= {}
        @@sockets ||= {}
        @response_servers = {
            "connect" => ConnectionPool.new,
            "status" => StatusServer.new,
            "message" => MessageServer.new
        }
    end

    def onopen(socket, handshake)
        @@connections[socket] = handshake 
        get_response_server(socket).onopen(socket)
    end

    def onmessage(socket, message)
        get_response_server(socket).onmessage(socket, message)
    end

    def onclose(socket)
        get_response_server(socket).onclose(socket)
    end

    def get_response_server(socket)
        uri = URI(@@connections[socket].path)
        case uri.path
        when "/status"
            return @response_servers["status"]
        when "/send_message"
            return @response_servers["message"]
        when "/"
            return @response_servers["connect"]
        end
    end
end
```

And here is one the classes responsible for handling the status EndPoint #3:`status_server.rb`

```
class StatusServer < Router
    def onopen(socket)
        puts "StatusServer onopen"
    end

    def onmessage(socket, message)
        puts "StatusServer onmessage => Recieved message: #{message}"
        socket.send get_connected_users.to_s
    end

    def onclose(socket)
        puts "StatusServer onclose"
    end

    def get_connected_users
        connected_users = {}

        @@sockets.each do |key, value|
            if value.count > 0 then
                connected_users[key] = value.count
            end
        end
        connected_users
    end
end
```

Am I going about this the correct/suggested way? And I am doing anything unsafe - as far as being asynchronous?

I have also looked into `Goliath`, but they have seemed to have removed the router from there project...